# Different styles for \citet and \citep in regards of the "and" or "&" between authors using natbib

Tags: natbib

Is it possible to use both "and" and "&" using `natbib`? I've been trying to work it out for a long time now and I just can't seem to figure this one out. All I can manage is to either have "and" or "&" on both.

What I want to achieve:

`\citet`: "Given_a and Given_b (2013)"

`\citep`: "(Given_a & Given_b, 2013)"

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) My opinion is that "&" is good only for commercial names.

Comment: Thanks! I agree, but my university insists of using a variation of the Harvard system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Afaik, `natbib` does not support this. But of course, a hack is always possible ... Try putting this in your preamble (assuming that originally both commands produce an `and`):

```
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{xstring}
\makeatletter
\let\origNAT@nmfmt\NAT@nmfmt
\def\NAT@nmfmt#1{%
  \ifNAT@swa
    \exploregroups\expandarg
    \StrSubstitute{#1}{ and }{ \& }[\mynatfmttemp]%
  \else
    \def\mynatfmttemp{#1}%
  \fi
  \origNAT@nmfmt{\mynatfmttemp}%
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: As of right now I'm using "&" as my current default, if I change it to "and" in the .bst file it changes the formatting of my reference list as well. It is however very close to what I'm looking for, the \citep and \citet worked perfectly when I changed to "and" :)

Comment: just exchange `{ and }` and `{ \& }` after `\StrSubstitute`.

Comment: If I exchange those I get the exact opposite of what I want. 

(authorA and authorB, 2013) and in text authorA & authorB (2013)

Comment: If you do the exchange I suggested in the comment and *keep your default* (where .bst produces &s), you should get the right thing. If I understand your situation correctly ...  Ahh, unless you mean that `\citep` and `\citet` behave just oppositely of what you want? In that case, stick an `\unless` in front of `\ifNAT@swa`. (Btw, my declaration of `\citep` above is superfluous ... remains of experimentation ... I'll delete it.)

Comment: Awesome! using `\unless` worked perfectly (using the previous example code). Thanks!